# Where can I find warming mats to prevent ice on access ramps?

Tags: electrical

I am looking for a warming mat or similar item to put on a handicapped ramp when there is ice or snow expected. My father is heavy, the wheelchair is difficult for me to push and particularly during bad weather when he needs to go to doctors.  I can't do the work myself, but hope there is a place online that someone knows of where I can purchase a mat along the ramp to warm so ice doesn't form.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Beware that these products can be quite expensive to operate, which is one reason why most homeowners stick to using salt and/or sand/grit.

Answer (score 2):

A good search term is "snow melting mat". That turns up multiple products that look suitable. In the meantime, using some salt on the ramp may help, as would adding anti-slip tape to the ramp if not already present.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a rooftop snow melt product to keep the ramp thawed.  These products go by a number of names -

- heat trace
- heat tape
- de-icing cable
- heating cable

etc. etc.  You have probably seen them on roofs, usually laid in a zigzag pattern to keep ice from building up under the snow.  They don't get real hot, just hot enough to melt snow.

[image: heat trace picture from heattracespecialists.com]

If you have a wooden ramp and the underside is accessible, you may be able to install it under the deck.  The installation should be fairly affordable - not a heck of a lot of time or labor.

Another thing to consider would be applying a very dark stain to the deck - darker colors absorb more heat from the sunlight and thaw faster than light colors.  Just make sure it's not something that makes the surface more slippery, in fact you may be able to get a finish made for non-slip traction.